# Alternative to Dreamweaver?

Tags: ide, dreamweaver, code-editor

I'm tired of Dreamweaver overwriting wrong files on the server,

so I'm looking for an alternative.

I want color-coding and possibility to open/save and edit files direct from the server, so I don't need to save files on my desktop first.

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to notepad++ when I had the same kind of problems with DreamWeaver. I tried some other programs too, but they were too complicated for my needs.
If all you need is color-coding and ftp-support, notepad++ is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Every web developer should be hand-writing their mark-up - all forms of automated abstraction inhibit your understanding and awareness of the code and create maintenance problems for the future. I'm quite a zealot about this, you may be able to tell.

On that basis, I can heartily recommend [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/): has code colouring, FTP and a huge amount of feature-sugar from line duplication to macros.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ extended with some plugins is a really handy replacement. Though I can't call it IDE, it does virtually everything a developer need. In my case (a lot of repetitive code) Texter (a small app working in background) makes notepadd++ even more handy. So, my suggestion is: **Notepad++ and Texter**.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Web Developer Express, which is the lightweight version of Visual Studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Mac you should take a look at [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)

Comment: I have heard of Coda, but I'm not using Mac. Do you know something similar Coda for PC?

Answer (score 1):

Well personally I use [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) but it doesn't support the facility to upload files to the server. You could get [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and this [FTP plugin](http://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/). I haven't tried Notepad++ but I'm sure that it isn't WYSIWYG.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just going blind, but that plugin doesn't seem to be available in the latest version of notepad++? :(

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central it's in the list somewhere.

Also found another editor, Intype. It's very nice and clean and a pretty interface, doesn't support FTP though but well worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/)?  It has all the features you've asked for, and there's a Windows version (as well as Mac and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver... Not my cup of tea, because it lacks good support for modern web programming with Javascript or PHP.

For primary design, I use WeBuilder from Blumentals. Its also a good and not expensive PHP and Javascript IDE with debugging support and also has good CSS support with a built-in CSS editor.
I'm not a big fan of text editors like Notepad++ as an IDE replacement, because you often need a lot of additional plug-ins to have similar features like a IDE. But for some files or quick editing nothing can beat such editors (I like Notepad++ the most on Windows).

So for Windows I would prefer WeBuilder for all things (design & programming).

You use only Windows? For Linux there are other alternatives too ;)

Answer (score 1):

When I searched an alternative for the Dreamweaver for PHP, I found some IDEs and one among them is [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/). Soon it became my favorite for my object oriented coding.

Here is the [download page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).

This has support for Zend and Symphony frameworks.

They also support File uploading.

Answer (score 0):

When developping in PHP, I generally use [Eclipse PDT](http://eclipse.org/pdt/).

If you are more oriented towards HTML/CSS/Javascript, you might be interested by [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), which is based on Eclipse too... Which means it can use lots of plugins, including some to work directly on a server, I suppose *(see [TM/RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/), for instance)*.

Note than Aptana can also be installed into an existing Eclipse installation, as a plugin.

Oh, also, I almost forgot : Eclipse is free, and there are both a free and a commercial version of Aptana.

*(One bad thing about Eclipse being it requires a quite powerful computer -- at least 2 cores and 2 GB of RAM, if you want to use any other application at the same time...)*

Answer (score 0):

[E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/), a [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) clone for Windows, claims to have FTP Support. But i haven't used this feature before.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want color-coding and possibility to open/save and edit files direct from the server, so I don't need to save files on my desktop first.*

The [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com/zftp.html) can highlight and fold *HTML files*, it integrates with *HTML Tidy* and can seamless edit files from the server via ftp/sftp.

It also has support for a host of [other languages](http://www.zeusedit.com/language.html) (i.e C/C++, C#, Java, Javascript, PHP, etc etc)